# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' from arcmap only

Tags: arcpy

I'm running a simple python script from arcmap that sends an html post and processes the response. This script runs just fine from pythonwin but for some reason I receive the following error when running the script from an arcmap toolbox: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

The python code and stack trace is below. I'm stumped why it would run outside of arcmap but not within. I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing. Hopefully someone can point it out. :)

```
for row in cursor:
        arcpy.SetProgressorLabel("Loading {0}...".format(row))
        url = "https://myurl.com"

        payload = "streetAddress="+row[0]+"&city="+row[1]+"&state="+row[2]+"&zip="+row[3]+"&apikey="+apikey+"&format=csv&census=false&censusYear=2000|2010&notStore=false&version=4.01"

        headers = {
            'accept': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            'access-control-allow-origin': "*"
            }           

        response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
        responseList = response.text.split(',')
```

StackTrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Development\PythonAddins\TAMUGeocoder.py", line 75, in <module>
    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 389, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 293, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 362, in prepare_url
    host = host.encode('idna').decode('utf-8')
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\encodings\idna.py", line 157, in encode
    labels = dots.split(input)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an arcpy issue -- the entire stack is within the `requests` library.

Comment: I agree completely, but the fact remains that it works run alone but not when run within arcmap. Any ideas why?

Comment: Is it the same build of Python?  32-/64-bit?

Comment: That was my first thought, but sys.version is showing the same for both: version: 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

Comment: None-type objects generally refer to a record with no associated geometry (null geometry), as a result of geometry errors or deleted objects flagged as deleted but still present due to unpacked tables. Files edited in QGIS often have this issue. ArcMap is unforgiving of these geometries.

Comment: My 10.3 doesn't have `requests` in it.  Did you install the same site library in both the ArcGIS and Python install?  Unfortunately, this sort of customization is probably outside the realm of Tech Support.

Comment: I'm still not sure what the issue was, but updating python to 2.7.11 fixed whatever it was. I checked that both python and ArcGIS were using the same version but perhaps there was something awry in the paths.. corrupted library.. just not sure. Thanks for all the input to those who answered.

Comment: I have experienced the same here!Python 2.7.12v. My code below:
---
import requests
requests.get("http://....")
--- That works fine running by the command window but when I try it by Arcgis Python Window the message shows:
---
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'utf_8_decode'
--- Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

The error

```py
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

often indicates that the attribute you are trying to split is `Null`, meaning there is no value in it to split.

You need to check the attribute is not Null before splitting.  Something like

```py
if not response.text == None: 
    responseList = response.text.split(',')
```

Comment: The problem is that the split is occurring within request library, not any code of mine and works fine in pythonwin, just not in arcmap which makes debugging more difficult. I have placed messages to try and track it down and have found the following. models.py calls host = host.encode('idna').decode('utf-8') and I placed a msg at that point displaying the url being passed which is correct. I then placed a msg in idna.py at the beginning of the encode() function to print the url being received there but that msg is never hit.  Stepping through a debugger everything looks fine, just not arcmap

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure what the issue was, but updating python to 2.7.11 fixed whatever it was. I checked that both python and ArcGIS were using the same version but perhaps there was something awry in the paths.. corrupted library.. just not sure. Thanks for all the input to those who answered.